# How to extend the kde part using distplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, kde-plasma

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax = sns.distplot(np.log10(df['income']), kde=True, hist=False, rug=False, kde_kws = {"bw": 0.35})
plt.xlabel('Gross national income per capita, Atlas method: $: 2016')
plt.ylabel('')  
plt.title('World Bank Gross Nationnal Income Per Capita')
plt.xlim(0.7, 6.3)
plt.ylim(-0.05, 0.73)
```

I use this code and got this plot:

[image: the plot I got]

but I want the plot to look like this:

[image: what the plot should look like]

Answer (score 1):

`sns.distplot()` has been deprecated in the current seaborn version (0.11.2). To draw a kde curve, `sns.kdeplot()` can be called directly, as it has parameters which help for this use-case.

Default, the kde is extended to 3 times the smoothing bandwidth, which usually works well. You can increase it with `sns.kdeplot(..., cut=4)`. If you want to cut off at a certain spot, you can combine with `clip=`, e.g.: `sns.kdeplot(..., cut=4, clip=(1,6))`.

`kdeplot` also has a `log_scale=True` parameter, which will take the log base 10 of the data to generate the curve, and show the x-axis in log scale. With `logscale=True`, `cut` and `clip` will also use log units.

Here is some code illustrating these options:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set()
data = 10 ** np.random.normal(3.5, 0.7, 20)
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(14, 3), sharey=True)
sns.kdeplot(data, log_scale=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Default')
sns.kdeplot(data, log_scale=True, cut=4, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('cut=4')
sns.kdeplot(data, log_scale=True, cut=4, clip=(1, 6), ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('cut=4, clip=(1, 6)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.kdeplot with logscale, cut and clip]

Comment: `kdeplot` has always been around: `distplot` is just calling it internally. It did gain a lot of features in 0.11.0, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'cut':3 to kde_kws

for example, kde_kws = {"bw": 0.35,'cut': 3}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).